# TypeMismatchException the provided ID is of a wrong type

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, type-mismatch

While working on my first app in Hibernate. While trying to retrieve a User object from the DB i am getting the following exception:

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class org.cw.form.User.  Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class
>   java.lang.String
>           at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:109)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:906)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:823)
>           at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:816)

I have created the USERS table with the following postgreSQL:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user2_id_seq; 

CREATE TABLE USERS(id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user2_id_seq'), user_name   varchar(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE , password varchar(45) NOT NULL, email varchar(45) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

And the User entity is defined as such:

```
@Entity @Table(name="USERS") public class User {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="USER_NAME", unique = true)
private String userName;

@Column(name="PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Column(name="EMAIL")
private String email; .. all the getters and setters...
```

I am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be easier to answer if you would show how do you retrieve Users. Based to message:

```
Provided id of the wrong type for class org.cw.form.User. 
Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
```

I guess you are providing String instead of correct type (Integer):

```
String userID = "1"; //Should be Integer userID = 1 instead
session.get(User.class, userID);
```

Answer (score 15):

I had a different culprit creating this issue: I had copy-pasted another entity's repository which used a String as primary key type.

So I had

```
class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    Integer id
```

in combination with

```
interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {
```

which produced the error message.

Simply changing the interface type from String to Integer resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

It often happens when you are going to perform `one-to-one` mapping with two entities that contain different types of primary keys in Spring JPA.

ex - you have two classes called `user` and `laptop`

**User class**

```
@Entity
class User{
   
    @Id
    private String userId;

    private String name;

 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = Laptop.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID",referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
 private Laptop laptop;

}
```

**Laptop class**

```
@Entity
class Laptop{

   @Id
   private int laptopId;

  private String brand;
}
```

**how to overcome this issue**

you can achieve it in 2 ways

1. replace `one-to-one` relationship to `one-to-many` on the parent entity

   ```
   @Entity
    class User{

        @Id
        private String userId;

        private String name;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity = Laptop.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID",referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
     private Laptop laptop;

    }
   ```
2. you can perform `one-to-one` relationship on the child entity

> ```
>   @Entity
> class Laptop{
>
>    @Id
>    private int laptopId;
>
>    private String brand;
>
>    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity = 
>     User.class)
>     @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID",referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
>      private User user;
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Why does the wrong type mismatch go away when you switch it to one-to-many. It works, I just tried it, but not sure why this works the way it does.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really know if it'll solve your issue, but since you are using sequences to generate ids on the db side, I think you should use a Sequence generator :

```
@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="user2_id_seq")
private Integer id;
```

Please see this post for details : [Hibernate sequence on oracle, @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068692/hibernate-sequence-on-oracle-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto)

Answer (score 4):

```
public User findClientByUsername(String login) {        
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("userName", login));
        return (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue, If you have made id as autoincrement then it doesn't require any setters, only get is fine as mentioned below.

```
  public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem, when I tried to use inheritance for the identifier class (@IdClass).