# How does the hibernate GenerationType.AUTO work in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, auto-generate

Using oracle/JPA Hibernate. I imported the schema which has values under student table in below fashion. Here is the example

```
100
85
80
70
1
```

I have below code:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
long id;
```

Now  when a new student is inserted , it does not inserts max value i.e 101 (max + 1). But inserting some values available in between
like 90. I am not sure how its possible ?

Does Hibernate internally create some database sequence and use then use last created value plus 1

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068692/hibernate-sequence-on-oracle-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto

Comment: then keep `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For oracle, yes it creates a sequence (probably named `hibernate_sequence`).

If you have existing values in the table, you probably want to update the sequence to give you ids larger than the existing ones (otherwise you'll soon get primary key errors).

Comment: i dropped the hibernate_sequence.But how i can i create it again. I expected it should be created automatically when app server restarts

Comment: Why did you drop it when I said "update the sequence".

Comment: Probably, check your oracle manual on how to alter sequences.

Comment: @Kayaman I have `@Id @Basic(optional = false) @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) private Integer id;` I get java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Error Code: 942. Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?. Please help.

Comment: @Kayaman I, also, tried with `@GeneratedValue`, but I get same previous result. I'm using Eclipse as JPA persistence provider.