# Oracle JPA GenerationType.AUTO with generator asks for "hibernate_sequence"

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use a defined sequence generation in Oracle JPA, along with GenerationType.AUTO like this:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_GEN_NAME", sequenceName = "MY_SQ_NAME")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "MY_GEN_NAME")
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

After running the hibernate validation it throws an error:

> Schema validation: missing sequence [hibernate_sequence]

I guess, it is ignoring my `MY_GEN_NAME` and trying to use that global sequence for id generation.

When I switch to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, it uses `SequenceHiLoGenerator` and it works fine.

Why is that happening, and is it possible to make the `GenerationType.AUTO` work with given sequence for Oracle (possibility to switch to other db)?

Comment: I think oracle does not have this feature. There is no "really" auto increment functionality. You have to use a sequence.

Comment: Wait. I think You didn't understand my question correctly. I do not want to use "auto increment". I want to use my own defined sequences along with `GenerationType.AUTO`. Let's say I have read only Oracle DB where sequences are created, but in the implementation I have to be ready to switch for MySQL (thats why `AUTO`, and not `SEQUENCE`). However when I'm using `AUTO` - even when I tell JPA what sequence to use, it still looks for or tries to create that global `hibernate_sequence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTO` says to the JPA provider, "choose what you want", and it will not use the "generator" attribute in that case.

If you want to use a SEQUENCE then set the strategy to `SEQUENCE`! That way it will use the sequence definition you have defined

Comment: What about that post http://stackoverflow.com/a/3068856/2630520.  I have just found it. Is it misleading?

Comment: It says exactly what i just said ... you select AUTO and you leave it to the JPA provider to decide. If you use "AUTO" with a different JPA provider you could get it using TABLE generator for example, or something else.

Comment: I mean that part: "Now, it is possible to use GenerationType.AUTO and still control the name of the sequence when the database uses sequences:" I did exackly like code in the example says and sequence is still "hibernate_sequence" - and this is not wanted.

Comment: You are trying to use something that is not in documentation of your JPA provider, is prone to change in the future (if it ever worked), and the person posting isn't even a developer of that software. Consequently you can conclude that that would be totally unreliable.

Comment: The point is that i have that in the code that I am suppsed to refactor. Its huge and old, but many people said that it worked. White I can't use it with the db schema that they provided. Im trying to figure out why they used AUTO along with @SequenceGenerator, when it is obviously not working. Thanks for Your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Though [hibernate-sequence-on-oracle-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068692/hibernate-sequence-on-oracle-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto) suggests that this will work, it appears that it is broken for some versions of Hibernate, see [HHH-10656](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10656).

Edit: Broken in 5.2.0, unbroken in 5.2.8.