# Hibernate not returning correct value for auto increment column with Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate with Oracle 12c.
After executing save operation hibernate not returning correct value of primary key(auto increment) that has sequence in DB.
In the below code UserId column(Auto increment) has a sequence in DB, 
After save operation in DB value is 81 but the returning value in hibernate is 3441.(Values are just example)
My code : 
`

```
User user = new User ();
User.setUserName(userName);
User.setRoleId(roleId);
getHibernateTemplate().save(User);
int userId = User.getUserId();
```

`

Note : Same code working fine with other DBs.

Comment: How is the table defined?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not handle the `strategy = GenerationType.AUTO` like some other dbs.  You will need to replace that annotation with something like these two

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
```

Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068692/hibernate-sequence-on-oracle-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto) as well.

Comment: Thanks for you response, After the above changes same issue is happening.

Comment: @Pramod - you say "after the above change..." Does that mean you have also created the MY_ENTITY_SEQ in Oracle? See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314

Comment: I renamed "MY_ENTITY_SEQ" with my sequence name in DB.