# oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."D_TEST"."DTESTID") in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to add newtest through postmethod and getting this error.
unable to find the cause can someone help me
I don't know why it is taking null can someone help me

```
2021-05-12 06:14:47.963 ERROR 7048 --- [nio-8099-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."D_TEST"."DTESTID")

2021-05-12 06:14:47.989 ERROR 7048 --- [nio-8099-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/Test] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."D_TEST"."DTESTID")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:553) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:970) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3756) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3736) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1063) ~[ojdbc8-19.8.0.0.jar:19.8.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3195) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3801) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.cg.controller.IDiagnosticTestController.addNewTest(IDiagnosticTestController.java:45) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
```

```
DiagnosticTest.java
package com.cg.entites;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;

@Entity
@Table(name="d_test")
//@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseStrategy.class)
public class DiagnosticTest implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="dtestid")
    private int dtestid;
    @Column(name="testname",nullable=true)
    private String testname;
    @Column(name="testprice",nullable=true)
    private Integer testprice;
    @Column(name="normalvalue",nullable=true)
    private String normalvalue;
    @Column(name="units")
    private String units;   
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tests")
    //@JsonIgnore
    private Set<DiagnosticCenter> diagnosticCenters = new HashSet<>();
    @JsonIgnore
    public int getDtestid() {
        return dtestid;
    }
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    public void setDtestid(int dtestid) {
        this.dtestid = dtestid;
    }
    public String getTestname() {
        return testname;
    }
    public void setTestname(String testname) {
        this.testname = testname;
    }
    public Integer getTestprice() {
        return testprice;
    }
    public void setTestprice(Integer testprice) {
        this.testprice = testprice;
    }
    public String getNormalvalue() {
        return normalvalue;
    }
    public void setNormalvalue(String normalvalue) {
        this.normalvalue = normalvalue;
    }
    public String getUnits() {
        return units;
    }
    public void setUnits(String units) {
        this.units = units;
    }
    public Set<DiagnosticCenter> getDiagnosticCenters() {
        return diagnosticCenters;
    }
    public void setDiagnosticCenters(Set<DiagnosticCenter> diagnosticCenters) {
        this.diagnosticCenters = diagnosticCenters;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DiagnosticTest [dtestid=" + dtestid + ", testname=" + testname + ", testprice=" + testprice
                + ", normalvalue=" + normalvalue + ", units=" + units + ", diagnosticCenters=" + diagnosticCenters
                + "]";
    }
}
```

DignosticCenter.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name="d_center")

public class DiagnosticCenter implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="dcenterid")
    private int dcenterid;
    @Column(name="name",nullable=true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name="contactNo",nullable=true)
    private String contactNo;
    @Column(name="address",nullable=true)
    private String address;
    @Column(name="contactEmail",nullable=true)
    private String contactEmail;
    @Column(name="servicesOffered",nullable=true)
    private String servicesOffered;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
                        CascadeType.PERSIST,
                        CascadeType.MERGE
                    })
    @JoinTable(name = "center_test", joinColumns = 
   { @JoinColumn(name = "dcenterId") }, 
   inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dtestId")})
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<DiagnosticTest> tests = new HashSet<>();
    
    
    


    public int getDcenterid() {
        return dcenterid;
    }


    public void setDcenterid(int dcenterid) {
        this.dcenterid = dcenterid;
    }


    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getContactNo() {
        return contactNo;
    }


    public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public String getContactEmail() {
        return contactEmail;
    }


    public void setContactEmail(String contactEmail) {
        this.contactEmail = contactEmail;
    }


    public String getServicesOffered() {
        return servicesOffered;
    }


    public void setServicesOffered(String servicesOffered) {
        this.servicesOffered = servicesOffered;
    }


    public Set<DiagnosticTest> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }


    public void setTests(Set<DiagnosticTest> tests) {
        this.tests = tests;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DiagnosticCenter [dcenterid=" + dcenterid + ", name=" + name + ", contactNo=" + contactNo + ", address="
                + address + ", contactEmail=" + contactEmail + ", servicesOffered=" + servicesOffered +  "]";
    }
}
```

DiagnosticTestRepository

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.cg.entites.DiagnosticCenter;
import com.cg.entites.DiagnosticTest;
import com.cg.exceptions.DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;


@Repository
public interface IDiagnosticTestRepository extends JpaRepository<DiagnosticTest,Integer>{

    /*public List<DiagnosticTest> getAllTest();
    public DiagnosticTest addNewTest(DiagnosticTest test);
    public List<DiagnosticTest> getTestsOfDiagnosticCenter(int dcenter_Id) throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;
    public DiagnosticTest updateTestDetail(DiagnosticTest test);
    public DiagnosticTest removeTestFromDiagnosticCenter(int dcenter_Id, DiagnosticTest test) throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;
*/
    public DiagnosticTest findByDiagnosticCenters(int dcenterid) throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;

    public Optional<DiagnosticTest> findById(int dtestid);
}
```

DiagnosticCenterRepository

```
package com.cg.dao;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.cg.entites.DiagnosticCenter;
import com.cg.entites.DiagnosticTest;
import com.cg.exceptions.DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;

@Repository
public interface IDiagnosticCenterRepository  extends JpaRepository<DiagnosticTest,Long>{


}
```

DiagnosticTestService

```
package com.cg.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.cg.entites.DiagnosticTest;
import com.cg.exceptions.DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;
import com.cg.exceptions.TestNotFoundException;


@Service
public interface IDiagnosticTestService {

    public List<DiagnosticTest> getAllTest();
    public DiagnosticTest addNewTest(DiagnosticTest test);
    public List<DiagnosticTest> getTestsOfDiagnosticCenter(int dcenterid) throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;
    public DiagnosticTest updateTestDetail(DiagnosticTest test);
    public DiagnosticTest removeTestFromDiagnosticCenter(int dcenterid) throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;
    
}
```

DiagnosticTestServiceImpl

```
package com.cg.service;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.cg.dao.IDiagnosticCenterRepository;
import com.cg.dao.IDiagnosticTestRepository;
import com.cg.entites.DiagnosticCenter;
import com.cg.entites.DiagnosticTest;
import com.cg.exceptions.DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;
import com.cg.exceptions.TestNotFoundException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;

@Service
public class IDiagnosticTestServiceImpl implements IDiagnosticTestService{
    @Autowired 
    private IDiagnosticTestRepository dtestrepo;
    @Autowired
    private IDiagnosticCenterRepository dcenterrepo;
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<DiagnosticTest> getAllTest() {
        return dtestrepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public DiagnosticTest addNewTest(DiagnosticTest test){
        
            DiagnosticTest dt=dtestrepo.save(test);
            System.out.println(dt);
            return dt;

        
    }

    @Override
    public DiagnosticTest updateTestDetail(DiagnosticTest test) {
        Optional<DiagnosticTest> dt=dtestrepo.findById(test.getDtestid());
        if(dt.isPresent()) {
            DiagnosticTest db=dt.get();
            db.setTestname(test.getTestname());
            db.setTestprice(test.getTestprice());
            db.setNormalvalue(test.getNormalvalue());
            db.setUnits(test.getUnits());
            db.getDiagnosticCenters();
            return dtestrepo.save(test);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<DiagnosticTest> getTestsOfDiagnosticCenter(int dcenterid) throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DiagnosticTest removeTestFromDiagnosticCenter(int dcenterid) throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException {
        DiagnosticTest dt=dtestrepo.findByDiagnosticCenters(dcenterid);
        System.out.println(dtestrepo.findByDiagnosticCenters(dcenterid));
       
           dtestrepo.delete(dt);
        return dt;
    }

}
```

DiagnosticTestController

```
package com.cg.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.cg.dao.IDiagnosticTestRepository;
import com.cg.entites.DiagnosticTest;
import com.cg.exceptions.DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException;
import com.cg.exceptions.TestNotFoundException;
import com.cg.service.IDiagnosticTestService;
import com.cg.service.IDiagnosticTestServiceImpl;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class IDiagnosticTestController {
   @Autowired
   IDiagnosticTestServiceImpl dtservice;
   @Autowired
   IDiagnosticTestRepository dtrepo;
 
@GetMapping("/dtest")
   public List<DiagnosticTest> findAllTests(){
       return dtrepo.findAll();
   }
  @PostMapping("/dtest/addtest")
   public ResponseEntity<DiagnosticTest> addNewTest(
           @RequestBody DiagnosticTest test){
    return new ResponseEntity<DiagnosticTest>(dtrepo.save(test),HttpStatus.OK);
}
/* @GetMapping("/dtest/{dcenterId}")
   public ResponseEntity<List<DiagnosticTest>> findTestsofDiagnosticCenter(
           @PathVariable("dcenterId") int dcenterId)  throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException{
       List<DiagnosticTest> tests=dtservice.getTestsOfDiagnosticCenter(dcenterId);
       if(tests!=null) {
           return new ResponseEntity<List<DiagnosticTest>>(tests,HttpStatus.OK); 
       }
      
          throw new  DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException("diagnostic center is not found");
    }*/
  @PutMapping("/dtest/dtests")
   public ResponseEntity<DiagnosticTest> updateTest(
           @RequestBody DiagnosticTest test){
       DiagnosticTest tests=dtservice.updateTestDetail(test);
       if(tests==null) {
           return new ResponseEntity("Sorry Tests are not available",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
       }
       return new ResponseEntity<DiagnosticTest>(test,HttpStatus.OK);
   }
   @DeleteMapping("/removeTestFromDiagnosticCenter")
   public ResponseEntity<DiagnosticTest> findByDiagnosticCenters(@RequestBody int dcenterid)  throws DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException{
       return new ResponseEntity<DiagnosticTest>(dtrepo.findByDiagnosticCenters(dcenterid), HttpStatus.OK);
      // throw new DiagnosticCenterNotFoundException("centerId not found");
   }
   
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: The error says: you can't insert null into "SCOTT"."D_TEST"."DTESTID", so check the record values that you are saving.

Answer (score 1):

Since your indicates you're using ORACLE, I have to ask if you plan to use a database-side sequence (I would recommend it). Assuming you've created it, you should wire it in using something like `@SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")`.

It would go with the same ID field you have your @GeneratedValue annotation placed on.

Here is another SO question that discusses it and shows the syntax: [Hibernate sequence on oracle, @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068692/hibernate-sequence-on-oracle-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto)

With that your ORM should be able to defer to Oracle to generate a proper sequence for the ID to be saved upon initial persistence of the object (i.e. when you would be INSERTING it for the first time).

I think you can get away with NOT using an Oracle sequence, but I'm not 100% sure. (When I used oracle, I always did).

Another good thread on the topic: [what is the use of annotations @Id and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)? Why the generationtype is identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603638/what-is-the-use-of-annotations-id-and-generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype)

Be sure to follow the "Oracle" tracks when reading these threads.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to try this out?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` as the strategy the table in database must have identity generator. As explained in JPA docs below -

> IDENTITY public static final GenerationType IDENTITY Indicates that
> the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using
> a database identity column.

For example in Oracle 12c you can define identity column as

```
create table test (
    test_col1 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
    test_col2 VARCHAR2(10)
    );
```